# MuleSoft - How to reference session variable and properties in global element properties field

Tags: properties, mule, expression, mule-studio, dataweave

I am trying to reference session variable + value from my properties file into global element properties such as web service consumer.

I keep on getting error which I think my code is not correct, do you guys what is the correct way to do so?

I am using Mule 3

**Session Var**

Name: lookupid
Value: abc

**.Properties file**

abc.application.opp.soap.serviceLibrary

**The code to reference the variable and properties in Web service consumer Service field or similar element properties field**

*#[p(sessionVars.lookupid ++ '.application.opp.soap.serviceLibrary')]*

**Expected Result in the element properties field**

abc.application.opp.soap.serviceLibrary

**Current Result**

Error, unable to startup due to the code that I trying to reference is not correct

Answer (score 0):

To reference a value read from properties use the p() operator.
Example:
`p('abc.application.opp.soap.serviceLibrary')`

See the documenation at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-reference-documentation#accessing-properties

Note that the properties file needs to be configured as usual in Mule 3.

Comment: Thanks, but you misinterpret my question. I am looking on how to reference a value read from properties plus or combine with flow/session variables.

Comment: Could you please add a more detailed example of what you are trying to do, including the Web Service Consumer part?